# Error in executing query while selecting features on map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, feature-class

I'm working on an ArcMap add-in that attempts to streamline doing feature class queries.  It mostly works, but there is one bizarre behavior that I'm attempting to track down.

There is one Feature Class in our database that gives slightly wonky results.  In almost all cases, it works fine, but if its layer is set to be visible, I cannot use the selection tool on the map.  Any attempt to do so comes up with 'There was an error executing the query' (it doesn't specify which layer is causing that, but setting that layer to be invisible does get rid of the error).

Now, the test data I'm using has three records in that Feature Class, and everything looks fine (the Shape fields, for instance, do have the expected Point values).

But it gets a bit weirder.  If I add that same feature class via File->Add Data->Add Data, it creates a Query Feature Class (usually I get an 'SDE Feature Class'; does that have something to do with whether the Feature Class is registered?).  There is no where clause in that Feature Class (neither in the Query itself, nor in the Definition Expression.  Nor was I given a chance to specify one in the creation process), but only two of the three records appear.

In fact, if I specify a DefinitionExpression of "Name='A'" (the value for the record that doesn't appear), nothing appears.  And if I explicitly set the where to "1=1", that is the same as having no DefinitionExpression.

Perhaps most importantly, however, having that Query Layer visible on the map does not impede selecting features.

And as a final data point, setting a where clause on my programmatically-created layer of "Name <> 'A'" (or something similar that rules out the record not appearing in the manually-created layer) does not help.  Selection still fails in every case I've tried.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what is going on or what else can I look at to get a better idea what it is?

If it matters, the database backing the feature class is SQL Server.

Comment: If you copy the problematic featureclass from sde into a file gdb, then point your layer to that, does it exhibit same behavior?

Comment: Also, when you add via File->Add Data->Add Data ... do you browse for a `.sde` file and drill down into that to choose the featureclass ?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Got taken off this issue for a while; came back to it finally.  Copying into a file GDB did not copy fields (only geometry; saw no way to change that), and no, that copied feature class did not exhibit the same behavior.

Exporting into a shape file, with all fields, did result in the same behavior.  Removing visibility of fields from original Feature Class made no change.  

And yes, to your second question about browsing and choosing.